# C++ multiplication of 2 matrices

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply 2 matrices with the overloaded * operator and print the result. Although seems like I cannot have more than 1 argument to the overloaded function. How do I pass the two matrices to the overloaded function? Please see my implementation below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;



class Class1
{
public:
    vector<vector<int> > matrix;
    vector<vector<int> >  tmp;
    Class1(vector<vector<int> > p):matrix(move(p)){}

    //This function is used to perform the multiplication operation between two square matrices
    void operator*(const Class1 &mat1,const Class1 &mat2)
     {

        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
           for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
           {
//            matrix[i][j]=0;
              for(int k=0;k<4;k++)
              {
                 tmp[i][j]=tmp[i][j]+(mat2.matrix[i][k]*mat1.matrix[k][j]);
              }
           }
        }
//      return tmp;
     }

    void PrintVector()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {

            for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                cout<<tmp[i][j]<<"  ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Class1 Matrix1 =   {{{ 21, 12, 13, 14 },
                       { 5, 6, 6, 8 },
                       { 9, 8, 7, 6 },
                       { 3, 2, 1, 1 } }};

    Class1 Matrix2 =   Matrix1;


    Class1 Matrix3 = Matrix1 * Matrix2;

    Matrix3.PrintVector();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can directly treat `matrix` as the first argument (without passing in function), and `mat2.matrix` as second. [Refer here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-c/)

Comment: @Udayraj Deshmukh Thanks, If I had Matrix4 = Matrix1 * Matrix2 * Matrix3, any idea how I could go about that? I can't just add a parameter in this case right?

Comment: Just keep it at 2 parameters and once that result is done then pass in the result of the first two matrices + Matrix3.

Comment: @CodeModeOn Basically it should directly work as cpp will calculate result of first two and then multiply it with third. Understandably you can write it as `Matrix4 = (Matrix1 * Matrix2 )* Matrix3`

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Your edit invalidates the answer provided. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**
You are doing this operations:

```
Class1 Matrix3 = Matrix1 * Matrix2;
```

The **return type** of `operator*` is **`Class1`**, not void.

**2.** 
When overloading an operator, the first operand is the `this`, and the second operand is the parameter you pass to the overloaded operator function. Hence, your definition should be:

```
  Class1 operator*(const Class1 &mat2)
```

Now, you can perform the multiplication of the two objects, and return a new object of type Class1 that carries the result. So, you get:

```
 Class1 operator*(const Class1 &mat2)
 {
     // Creating a reference for the `this` object to minimize changes in code
      Class1& mat1 = this;

     // perform the multiplication between mat1 and mat2
     for ( ... )
      .......

     // return the newly created object
     return tmp;

 }
```

Comment: `Class1 operator*(const Class1 &mat1, const Class1 &mat2)` as a free function will also work.

Comment: @Aziz- If I had Matrix4 = Matrix1 * Matrix2 * Matrix3, any idea how I could go about that? I can't just add a parameter in this case right?

Comment: @CodeModeOn: The first `*` will perform the multiplication `Matrix1 * Matrix2`, returning a temporary matrix (let's call it `tmp`), then the second `*` will perform `tmp * Matrix3` and the result will be stored in  `Matrix 4`. So this is not a three-operand operation. It's 2 two-operand operations.